# Convert IEnumerable into a CSV file in memory and email as attachment

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send an email containing a CSV attachment without actually writing the file to disk before I attach it.

This is what I have got so far.

```
public void EmailBillSiteReport(int billId, string siteNumber)
{
    var bill = GetElectricityBillMain(billId);
    var billSites = bill.ElectricityBillSites.Where(x => x.SiteNo == siteNumber);    
    Helpers.EmailHelper.ConstructAndSendEmail("sample@emailaddress.com", billInvoices.JoinStrings(","));       
}
```

Extension method

```
public static class ListHelper
{
    public static string JoinStrings<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, string separator)
    {
        var stringValues = values.Select(item =>
        (item == null ? string.Empty : item.ToString()));
        return string.Join(separator, stringValues.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Method to send

```
public static void ConstructAndSendEmail(string sendTo, string csv)
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);

    writer.Write(csv);

    System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
    attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.csv";

    MailMessage md = new MailMessage();

    md.From = new MailAddress("samplefromaddress@email.com");
    md.To.Add(sendTo);

    md.Subject = "sample subject";
    md.Body = "sample body";

    md.Attachments.Add(attach);

    md.IsBodyHtml = false;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
    client.Host = smtpSection.Network.Host;
    client.Port = smtpSection.Network.Port;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Send(md);

    //close the stream
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Dispose();
    ms.Close();
}
```

The email arrives with a CSV attachment, and is 268bytes large. There is nothing in it. I want to turn the contents of my IEnumerable into comma separated strings and have it attached as a CSV, preferably keeping the property names as headers. My alternative is to use LinqToCsv and save the file first then pick it up, but I would prefer to do the whole thing in memory as the file is not required to be saved.

What am I doing wrong here?

**edit**

If I add in [Scott Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/?date=2010-02-04) ToCsv extension method and pass this into my ConstructAndSendEmail, the file still comes through empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewind the stream before using it:

```
writer.Write(csv);
writer.Flush();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

---

A more compact alternative:

```
MemoryStream ms =
   new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(csv));
```

With this compact form, you are directly transforming the CSV string into a MemoryStream without using a Writer.

Comment: Thanks, this now actually writes something to the CSV, also includes no first row for headers, and has stuff like this System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.ElectricityBillMain_827C6BB6F398AD1264BB6ACFCAF0078B5B92E2D58D2A3F20217B584CE8DBB8CF in various sections

Comment: Yes, I am getting blanks coming through and as I said above, entity id's, I need to figure out how to remove them before I accept anything.

Comment: The entity IDs indicate that your value objects don't have a proper ToString() method. But that's beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: If I use your 'more compact alternative' can I remove the writer.Flush() altogether as currently it is throwing me an error if I leave that in at the end of the method? I still have writer.Flush() writer.Dispose() and ms.Close() at the end of the method, is this correct

Comment: Im getting "Memory stream is not expandable." when I hit writer.Dispose at the end of the method